# How to create a liveurl preview of link using AngularJS or javascript, and make it clickable?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, firebase

I do have a textarea element and I use angular for data-binding. I would like to capture the url in the string entered by the user, and generate a clickable live preview of that url. Any idea on how I can accomplish this using AngularJS or JavaScript? Just like Facebook.
Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you can do this client-side, but if you can it'll require somehow fetching the target page and rendering somehow. I'm almost certain that other sites that do this use an ajax call to get their server to do the heavy-lifting.

Comment: Solarshado and @Martin I'm still in brainstorming and reading some material regarding open graph. I came across this open-graph-scrapper which could eventually allow me to get all the metadata from the URL, then use a directive a live screenshot with title and description, all clickable. I'm trying to see how implement all that.

Comment: I am working on the same issue. I have used LiveURL in the past but the image and Title fields have changed so its not working properly anymore. However I have found an API service that does it for free for x amount per hour. You want http://www.linkpreview.net/

Comment: @Darren Street thanks for the answer, very helpful, this answers my question. In the meantime, I'll keep looking for a free API service, or see how can actually write the code myself. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You would need some server to do this for you.

You could either use a public service such as https://screenshotlayer.com/, https://www.url2png.com/
or You could run your own server with one of these libraries: https://github.com/brenden/node-webshot or https://github.com/vbauer/manet

Comment: I just looked at these services and API, and it looks like they only provide screenshots. I may be wrong, but that's  my first impression. I'm I right?

Comment: if that isn't what you asked about then i misunderstood your question, please clarify what yo meant

Comment: Sure! I'm trying to find a way to detect url from a textarea, extract metadata, then generate a clickable  live preview with title and description. Just like in Facebook when we share/post links.